# R: How to calculate mean for each row with missing values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I want to calculate means over several columns for each row in my dataframe containing missing values, and place results in a new column called 'means.' Here's my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,4,5),B=c(0,6,8),C=c(9,NA,1))
  A B  C
1 3 0  9
2 4 6 NA
3 5 8  1
```

The code below successfully accomplishes the task if columns have no missing values, such as columns A and B.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(means=mean(A:B, na.rm=T))

     A     B     C   means
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     0     9   1.5
2     4     6    NA   5.0
3     5     8     1   6.5
```

However, if a column has missing values, such as C, then I get an error:

```
> df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(means=mean(A:C, na.rm=T))
Error: NA/NaN argument
```

Ideally, I'd like to implement it with dplyr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(means=rowMeans(., na.rm=TRUE))
```

The `.` is a "pronoun" that references the data frame `df` that was piped into `mutate`.

> ```
>   A B  C    means
> 1 3 0  9 4.000000
> 2 4 6 NA 5.000000
> 3 5 8  1 4.666667
> ```

You can also select only specific columns to include, using all the usual methods (column names, indices, `grep`, etc.).

```
df %>% 
  mutate(means=rowMeans(.[ , c("A","C")], na.rm=TRUE))
```

> ```
>   A B  C means
> 1 3 0  9     6
> 2 4 6 NA     4
> 3 5 8  1     3
> ```

Comment: That works! The help for rowwise() says "to allow you to work with list-variables in summarise and mutate without having to use [[1]]." However, looks like there is no way to avoid square brackets.

Comment: `rowwise` is also notoriously slow.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple to accomplish in base R as well:

```
cbind(df, "means"=rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE))
  A B  C    means
1 3 0  9 4.000000
2 4 6 NA 5.000000
3 5 8  1 4.666667
```

The `rowMeans` performs the calculation.and allows for the na.rm argument to skip missing values, while `cbind` allows you to bind the mean and whatever name you want to the the data.frame, df.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error in OP's code, we can use the concatenate function `c` to get those elements as a single `vector` and then do the `mean` as `mean` can take only a single argument.

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(means = mean(c(A, B, C), na.rm = TRUE))
#     A     B     C    means 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     3     0     9 4.000000
#2     4     6    NA 5.000000
#3     5     8     1 4.666667
```

---

Also, we can use `rowMeans` with `transform`

```
transform(df, means = rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE))
#  A B  C    means
#1 3 0  9 4.000000
#2 4 6 NA 5.000000
#3 5 8  1 4.666667
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, means := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the error, @akrun. Your answer with rowwise() is elegant. But for a large range of columns, say A to Z, is there a way to  concatenate without listing each individually in the c function?

Comment: @Irakli Inside the `dplyr` `mutate`, I find other options are not working i.e. `unlist` and stuff.  So, I would go by the eipi10's solution with `rowMeans` as it is fast and uses `dplyr`

Comment: that explains why I had so much trouble with mutate & mean. Thank you, @akrun!